# Bourbon/Sass: #{$all-text-inputs} with hover or focus?

Tags: sass, bourbon

According to the [Bourbon docs](http://thoughtbot.com/bourbon/#html5-input-types), you can use 
 `#{$all-text-inputs}` to turn this:

```
#{$all-text-inputs} {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

into this:

```
input[type="email"], input[type="number"],   input[type="password"], input[type="search"],
input[type="tel"],   input[type="text"],     input[type="url"],      input[type="color"],
input[type="date"],  input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"],
input[type="month"], input[type="time"],     input[type="week"] {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Is there a way with Bourbon or Sass to apply `:hover` or `:focus` to each?

`#{$all-text-inputs:hover}` and `#{$all-text-inputs}:hover` did not work.

Comment: BTW - a Bourbon tag would be nice if anyone with 1500+ rep woud like to create one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to just nest the `:hover` and `:focus` styles using the Sass [parent selector](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#referencing_parent_selectors_):

```
#{$all-text-inputs} {
  border: 1px solid green;
  &:hover, &:focus {
    // some styles
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How about `#{$all-text-inputs-hover}` instead of `#{$all-text-inputs:hover}`?

And for the focus `#{$all-text-inputs-focus}`

Look the spec again
http://bourbon.io/docs/#html5-input-types