# Creating selector aliases in sass

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

To avoid writing it out multiple times, i'd like to create a 'texty-input' alias for the selector:

```
input[type=text],
input[type=url],
input[type=tel],
input[type=number],
input[type=color],
input[type=email]
```

Is there any way of creating a variable/alias for this commonly-used but verbose selector in sass?

Comment: cant just use `input`?

Comment: @Pilot: That would match any input. Not what he wants.

Comment: @cimmanon thanks, that answers my question. This question is also related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254453/bourbon-sass-all-text-inputs-with-hover-or-focus

Comment: For anyone in the future looking for a pure CSS way: [it's currently in the editor's draft](http://tabatkins.github.io/specs/css-aliases/#custom-selectors)